# Cannot configure Civicrm after installation of the plugin

Tags: configuration

I installed civicrm plugin on a Wordpress site. 
When I click on the link to configure it 
( CiviCRM is almost ready. You must configure CiviCRM for it to work), 
I got a blank page.
All the versions of component (php, MySql, Wordpress) meet the requirements.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: check php or apache/nginx logs for detailed error

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM.  Could you confirm that you've followed all the installation instructions to the letter in the documentation, in [link](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/)